# Algorithm for finding the position of the shadow

Tags: jquery, algorithm, css

Please help me to find out the algorithm for finding the position of the shadow, depending on rotation of the object.

For example, I have PNG image with `-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) Xpx Ypx 0px);` and `-webkit-transform: rotate(Zdeg);`

I want to write a jQuery script that calculates `X` and `Y` (shadow position), depending on `Z` (rotation in degrees).

By experimenting I have made ​​a table:

```
 X | -5| -5| 0 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 0 | -5| -5| – Shadow position

 Y | 0 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 0 | -5| -5| -5| 0 | – Shadow position

 Z | 0 | 45| 90|135|180|225|270|315|360| – Rotation
```

Comment: @optimus-prime http://jsfiddle.net/RKmus/

Answer (score 1):

```
X = cos(Z) ? -5 * (cos(Z) / abs(cos(Z))) : 0;
Y = sin(Z) ? -5 * (sin(Z) / abs(sin(Z))) : 0;

or

X = -5 * cos(Z);
Y = -5 * sin(Z);

and take care of the degrees to radians;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mBQxK/4

Comment: PS. I think a better way to do this is to have a shadow-image inside another div, and have both divs rotate at the same speed.

Answer (score 1):

```
X = -5 * cos(Z);
y = 5 * sin(Z);
```